# Pass variable when creating elements in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-dom

I really need your help.
I have an array useState with elements 'Screen'. I dynamically add elements to useState to add them to the page.

I need to make small changes to each of these elements, the "ID" variable in the Screen. I want to select on creation through a for loop. I don't know how to do it. Please look at an example. I simplified it for better understanding

```
//Screen.js
let ID
import React, {useEffect} from "react";

const Screen =()=>{
    useEffect(()=>{
           socket.on(ID,async () => {console.log(ID)})
    },[])
    return(
            <canvas id={ID} className='canvas' width={600} height={400}> </canvas>
    )
}
export default Screen



//List.js
import Screen from './Screen';
import React, {useEffect, useState} from "react";

const List = ()=>{
    const [state, setState] = useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
            for (let i=0;i<5;i++){
                setState(state =>[...state, <Screen key={i}/>])
            }
    },[])
    return(
        <div>
            {state}
        </div>
    )
}
export default List
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your answer is a bit confusing, but i would like to try to give you an answer.

Is the below solution what are you looking for?

```
const Screen = ( {id} )=> {
    useEffect(()=> {
        socket.on(id,async ()=> {console.log(id)})
    }, [id])

    return <canvas id={id}
            className='canvas'
            width={600}
            height={400}
           />
}
```

```
const List = ()=>{
    const [state, setState] = useState([]);
    useEffect(()=>{
            for (let i=0;i<5;i++){
                setState(state =>[...state, <Screen key={i} id={i}/>])
            }
    },[])
    return(
        <div>
            {state}
        </div>
    )
}
```